# Audit failed because I voted as duplicate - seems counterproductive/-intuitive

Tags: bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

So I have a suggestion for the audit system for Close Votes:

**I suggest that the audit system always let you pass if you vote to close as a duplicate!**

Because failing on this premise seems counterintuitive. The message you get is something along the lines:

> *STOP, you didn't pay attention - this question don't have any problems etc.*

***But:*** The fact that I (as the first person) identified that it is actually a duplicate, and take the effort to find the duplicate and link to it - that makes me actually have paid more attention and put more effort into the review than anyone else looking at that question before.

I've experienced this a couple of times, where I actually remembered that this question had been answered previously, and possibly had better answers than the ones presented in the audit question.

The audit system can't possibly know if a question is actually a duplicate, and almost every question asked on any site could be a valid dupe - but granted that someone takes the time to actually identify it. So I think no matter what you should pass for this and not fail.

That's just my 2 cents.

Comment: Re *"always let you pass if you vote to close as a duplicate"*: What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yes please explain what could go wrong in this context - or maybe you don't understand my reasoning?

Comment: How can it go "more" wrong than what happens all the times in review? Please enlighten me.

Comment: This should probably be posted on Meta Stack Overflow. However, it already has been, multiple times. [This is probably the canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304100/review-audit-failed-mark-as-duplicate-is-inappropriate-even-though-it-is-a). Here's [another one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421570/failed-an-audit-because-i-flagged-as-duplicate-when-it-really-is-one).

Comment: Yeah - I can live with knowing I'm right - but I still think it would be more natural to let somebody pass, who to the extra effort. Isn't that the whole point of audits, to be sure people put in effort? But whatever..

Comment: Well, This_is_NOT_a_forum's concerns are valid: if you would always pass an audit by voting to close a question as a duplicate, then a robo-reviewer could just *always* vote to close questions in the review queues as duplicates. They'd pass all the audits, and, in the case of the non-audits, the system wouldn't know that their decision was wrong. This would be a pretty pathological case, admittedly, but it would still be a flaw. Should the review queues be optimized to best stop robo-reviewers, or to trust the users? Unfortunately, my experience as a mod says the former...

Comment: In that case, robo reviewers would "reveal" themselves by linking to random dupes, and they could be banned on that account. But yeah, I guess it's a matter of philosophy after all.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Robo-reviewers already reveal themselves with non-sense reviews and/or an inhumane review frequency. Does SO have the bandwidth to find and ban them?

Comment: Then I don't really see the problem - but then again, I (obviously) don't see everything. IMO, it would be rather easy to "autoban" someone who reviewed close votes with an unnaturally high frequence of dupe votes (like 90% dupe votes), since this would never be the case for real reviews. Problem solved!

Comment: Actually, to detect exploiting this there would be at least 2 metrics: First, you needed to vote all questions in the close vote queue as "Close" - this could be detected. And then, all those needed to be closed with the reason "Duplicate" - this could also be detected. Someone can probably find data to detect some valid thresholds where no "real" reviewers would have a problem, but where robots would be banned automatically for exploiting the system. I don't really see any problem with that.

Comment: And should you in *extremely* rare cases be autobanned for this where you actually made good reviews, you could catch a mod, and have them review your history - and you would of course get review privileges back if your reviews are actually valid. But I think this would be extremely rare if the thresholds are set in a clever way.

Comment: If anybody can fetch the data, it would be interesting to see the average percentage of dupe votes in the Close review queue for users across all sites. And then take the discussion from there, when we know the gap between reality and exploitation...

Comment: @CodyGray Why would MSO be a better place for this?  If it is a problem that extends to all SE sites, then isn't MSE better?  This user came across the issue on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that the review queues and their inherent bugginess had made it onto other SE sites. We've been proudly hosting the complaining about them on MSO for many years now. The problem with the suggested auto-bans for too many reviews of the same type is that *the damage has already been done*. Better to catch users robo-reviewing before they do too much damage.

Comment: I would argue that this is an excellent compromise because it would only allow abuse in the "negative direction"– bad actors could try and close good posts, _but wouldn't be able to green-light bad ones_ (which is the [main motivation for the audit system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621) in the first place). I feel like that adequately addresses the (valid) concern about opening an "always-pass" audit loophole.